When CTI Server in in dummy mode Why does the AUX status in TMAC revert back to the default[Automatically] after being changed to Available?
SMS API logs shows as below on aux status change
AES wrapper log
tmac server logs
In tmac server below log lines are observed

2024-07-31 11:55:11,313 [87] DEBUG VoiceLibrary.TServerManager -
ChangeStateToAutoIn():10002: 2024-07-31 11:55:11,815 [87] DEBUG
VoiceLibrary.TServerManager - ChangeStateToAutoIn->GetAgentState
return:0: 2024-07-31 11:55:11,815 [87] DEBUG
VoiceLibrary.TServerManager - ChangeStateToAutoIn():SetAgentState::
2024-07-31 11:55:11,816 [87] DEBUG VoiceLibrary.TServerManager -
ChangeStateToAutoIn->SetAgentState return:-1: 2024-07-31 11:55:11,816
[87] WARN AMACWebServerLogic.AgentSession -
[4001_10002]-[aea51546-8661-43a3-95e5-e728a7988150] ChangeStatus:
ChangeStatus failed: -1: 2024-07-31 11:55:31,817 [87] DEBUG
AMACWebServerLogic.AgentSession -
[4001_10002]-[aea51546-8661-43a3-95e5-e728a7988150] ChangeStatus:
newStat=Error:-1: 2024-07-31 11:55:31,817 [87] DEBUG
AMACWebServerLogic.AgentSession -
[4001_10002]-[aea51546-8661-43a3-95e5-e728a7988150]
AgentStatusManager_AgentStatusChanged: Error:-1: 2024-07-31
11:55:31,817 [87] DEBUG AMACWebServerLogic.AgentSession -
OnStatusChange: Error:-1:

From the logs, it looks like some config/ agent feature issue

When using CTI server in dummy mode, Agents logging into Agent desktop should have feature IsManualEnabled enabled in table AGT_AgentFeature, to be able to change status to Available and receive dummy voice calls from CTI.
Having this feature disabled will not allow agent status to be changed from default to available.
